# jQuery animation not happening when followed by a dequeue event

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm trying to display an image while I'm doing some Ajax updating (which I've placed in a queue).  Here's the code

```
        $(".SaveButton").click(function () {
            $(".SavingImage").fadeIn("fast");
            $(this).dequeue("Updates");
            $(".SavingImage").fadeOut("fast");
            $(".ResultItem").data("isDirty", false)
        });
```

.show() and .hide() work, but not the animations.  Let me know if more code is needed, I figured this would suffice.

Comment: Where are you queuing the animations for the `Updates` queue on `.SaveButton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the function in the call back of the animate function. Something like this:

```
$(".SaveButton").click(function () {
   $(".SavingImage").fadeIn("fast",function(){
     $(this).dequeue("Updates");
   });
   $(".SavingImage").fadeOut("fast");
   $(".ResultItem").data("isDirty", false));
});
```